# while running mongodb it is showing warnings related to access control. Read write access is undirected

Tags: python, mongodb

While running MongoDB the warnings are

```
WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database    
      Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development, this isn't an issue. You're simply using an insecure database. This means that anyone could connect your database and execute any query they'd like without restriction.

If you'd like to use a secure database, look into the `--auth` option when running mongodb.